# Loading Georeferenced maps from QGIS to Avenza Maps - can only WSG84 UTM be used?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, linear-referencing, avenza

Am new to this.

Tried to upload to Avenza Maps the following 2 georeferenced versions of the same map.

1. WSG84 UTM 56S (QGIS: linear transformation) - Produces a slight
   vertically squished map
2. GDA94 Zone 56 (QGIS: linear
   transformation) - Produces an intact map

Understand that Avenza uses WSG84 UTM
https://support.avenza.com/hc/en-us/articles/4401807661716-Mapping-Fundamentals

So it would be preferable to use (1), but the map is slightly squished. I thought linear transformation should leave the map intact, according to the documentation.

---

https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html
"The **Linear algorithm** is used to create a world file and is different from the other algorithms, as it does not actually transform the raster pixels. It allows positioning (translating) the image and uniform scaling, but no rotation or other transformations. It is the most suitable if your image is a good quality raster map, in a known CRS, but is just missing georeferencing information. At least 2 GCPs are needed."

Comment: I've successfully uploaded multiple maps in NAD83 UTM 13N.

Comment: Thank you for that feedback. Just received feedback that the WSG84 UTM polynomial transformation was pretty accurate. WSG84 UTM linear was not. GDA94 was off by 2 meters.